# How to build the latest version of Banshee on Ubuntu

Tags: compiling, banshee, mono

I am trying to build banshee but I can't get it to compile. I used the [banshee Source Tarball](http://banshee.fm/download/archives/2.9.1/), and the [banshee github code](https://github.com/GNOME/banshee).

Here is a script on what I already did:

```
#!/bin/bash

# dependencies

sudo apt-get install aptitude
sudo aptitude build-dep banshee

sudo apt-get install git-core autoconf p7zip-full automake libtool intltool gcc make libgconf2.0-cil-dev libgconf2-dev boo libboo-cil-dev mono-gmcs libglib2.0-cil-dev libgstreamer1.0-dev gstreamer-1.0 libgstreamer0.10-dev libgstreamer-plugins-base0.10-dev gtk-sharp2-gapi libdbus-glib1.0-cil-dev libmono-addins-cil-dev libgudev3.0-cil sqlite3 libsqlite3-dev libdbus-glib-1-dev libmtp-dev libgpod-cil-dev libmono-zeroconf-cil-dev libgtk-3-dev monodevelop libgudev3.0-cil* 

#downloading 
# wget http://ftp.gnome.org/pub/GNOME/sources/banshee/2.9/banshee-2.9.1.tar.xz
# 7z x banshee-2.9.1.tar.xz
# 7z x banshee-2.9.1.tar
git clone git://github.com/GNOME/banshee.git
cd banshee

#dependencies: PASSED 
git clone git://github.com/mono/gtk-sharp.git
cd gtk-sharp
./autogen.sh
make
sudo make install 
cd ..

# gstreamer-sharp-1.0: PASSED 
git clone git://github.com/inizan-yannick/gstreamer-sharp-1.0.git
cd gstreamer-sharp-1.0
./autogen.sh
make
sudo make install 
cd ..

# taglib-sharp: PASSED 
git clone git://github.com/mono/taglib-sharp.git
cd taglib-sharp
./autogen.sh 
make
sudo make install
cd ..

# configuring, make and installing banshee
./configure
make
sudo make install
```

At this time I get the following error, when I `make` banshee.

> error CS0006: Metadata file
>   `/usr/local/lib/cli/gstreamer-sharp-1.0/gstreamer-sharp.dll' could not
>   be found

But the `configure`;`make`;`sudo make install` of gstreamer-sharp-1.0 **PASSED** without any issues.

Comment: It shouldn't be looking for a dll, it should be looking for a .so.

Comment: @hbdgaf, banshee uses mono. Mono names stuff `.dll`.

Comment: Did you succeed?

Comment: @StevenRoose No. I gave up. Not worth the time and effort. At least not for me.

Answer (score 0):

The repository you're using for gstreamer-sharp is wrong, it should be git://anongit.freedesktop.org/gstreamer/gstreamer-sharp instead (and checkout the tag 0.99.0 after you clone).

Also, I've seen some distros fail to load assemblies located in /usr/local, then you may want to try to fix this problem by using the /usr prefix (passing it in the configuration phase: `./autogen.sh --prefix=/usr`).

Comment: I `sudo make uninstall` everything. Tried the repo you suggested, and used the `--prefix=/usr` flag u suggested but, when `make` banshee i still get the aforementioned error?

Comment: that is certainly weird, what does the gstreamer-1.0.pc file contain?

Comment: oh, and you need to ./configure again, not just make

Comment: I did that. I `sudo make uninstall` and `./configure`;`make`;`sudo make install`.. on make it gives the error....

Comment: what does your gstreamer-1.0.pc file contain?

Comment: Apologize for the late reply. Here is the content from the [`gstreamer-1.0.pc`](http://pastebin.ubuntu.com/8181615/)

Answer (score 0):

I tried to compile it by myself with no go results. Nevertheless I did a search and had came with the page:  [banshee Download (DEB, RPM, TXZ, XZ)](http://pkgs.org/download/banshee)

There I found [**banshee_2.9.0+really2.6.2-2ubuntu2.1_amd64.deb**](http://pkgs.org/ubuntu-14.04/ubuntu-proposed-universe-amd64/banshee_2.9.0+really2.6.2-2ubuntu2.1_amd64.deb.html), not  a direct answer but, in my case, Amazon Player was safe and sound (not working before)  as well (not problematic) the other plugins.
I found this a much easier approach.
I´ll continue to solve the compilation issue you mentioned above

Comment: I installed the package, and it's still the same version(`2.6.2`) Even after a reboot?

Comment: banshee_2.9.0+really2.6.2-2ubuntu2.1_amd64.deb
Description

banshee - Media Management and Playback application

    Distribution: Ubuntu 14.04 LTS
    Repository: Ubuntu Proposed Universe amd64
    Package name: banshee
    Package version: 2.9.0
    Package architecture: amd64
    Package type: deb
    Installed size: 13,51 KB
    Download size: 2,60 MB
    Binary package: banshee_2.9.0+really2.6.2-2ubuntu2.1_amd64.deb
    Source package: banshee

Comment: It says 2.9.0 + really 2.6.2. Is that a massive troll? Is it really just 2.6.2?